# Visualizing shapefile of polygons in Google Earth Engine Explorer

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine-explorer

I've just imported a shapefile of polygons in Google Earth Engine Explorer using the website http://shpescape.com/

The problem is that the polygons do not appear when I want to make them visible in the Google map.

May you help me with this ?

Comment: Likely a projection issue. What projection is your shapefile in?

Comment: Oh I did not think about that ... UTM 18 South !

Answer (score 2):

Two things to try:

1) make sure that the correct geometry column is specified e.g.:

```js
ee.FeatureCollection('fn:xxx', '<geometry_column_name>')
```

2) As others @Mapperz suggested, check that your projection matches what's expected. The Fusion table interface is a good tool for this, IMO, because you can plot the geometry that you expect and see if it shows up.